# How do I use browserify/parcel with express?

Tags: node.js, express, browserify, web3js, parceljs

This will be a long one so bare with me, I've had this code for my dapp that used a couple of libraries imported and a .json build file for my solidity contract, the first few lines looked like this

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import configuration from '../build/contracts/MyNFT.json';

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = configuration.networks['5777'].address;
const CONTRACT_ABI = configuration.abi;

const web3 = new Web3(
    Web3.givenProvider || 'IP ADDRESS, idk if I should remove that when posting but I did'
);

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);


//Initializing Moralis
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;
const fs = require("fs");
```

Now this worked good before as I was using parcel, now that I want a backend I setup a new express js project and wanted to first get whatever I had before working, so when I set everything up and ran the html file that used this js file, I realized that it doesnt work and I'll need something like browserify, now when I try to use browserify on that js file it says "**'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'**"

Is there any way for me to fix that or even use parcel with that project instead?

I tried another way of importing the packages and it still didn't work, excuse my ignorance but when I used parcel and ran build, it ran its server on my pc so is there any way where I can manually build the js file then link that new bundled js file in my html file and use expressjs as usual?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple, I installed Parcel and then used

```
parcel build file.js
```

Then I linked the new js file in the dist folder to my html file and everything worked.